How to remove multiple entries by a single ldap request in unboundid?
I investigated https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/ldap/sdk/DeleteRequest.html
and looks like it allows to remove only a single entry(with subtree if delete subtree control is passed).
In my use case I want to remove multiple sibling entries and it could be hundreds siblings. I don't want to make hundreds of ldap calls. Is there way to do the job using a single call ?

I think you'd use MultiUpdateExtendedRequest. Based on the example that's in the documentation, it might look something like this:
 MultiUpdateExtendedRequest multiUpdateRequest =
      new MultiUpdateExtendedRequest(
           MultiUpdateErrorBehavior.ABORT_ON_ERROR,
           new DeleteRequest("cn=entry to delete,dc=example,dc=com");,
           new DeleteRequest("cn=entry to delete2,dc=example,dc=com"););

 MultiUpdateExtendedResult multiUpdateResult =
      (MultiUpdateExtendedResult)
      connection.processExtendedOperation(multiUpdateRequest);
 if (multiUpdateResult.getResultCode() == ResultCode.SUCCESS)
 {
   // The server successfully processed the multi-update request, although
   // this does not necessarily mean that any or all of the changes
   // contained in it were successful.  For that, we should look at the
   // changes applied and/or results element of the response.
   switch (multiUpdateResult.getChangesApplied())
   {
     case NONE:
       // There were no changes applied.  Based on the configuration of the
       // request, this means that the attempt to create the user failed
       // and there was no subsequent attempt to add that user to a group.
       break;
     case ALL:
       // Both parts of the update succeeded.  The user was created and
       // successfully added to a group.
       break;
     case PARTIAL:
       // At least one update succeeded, and at least one failed.  Based on
       // the configuration of the request, this means that the user was
       // successfully created but not added to the target group.
       break;
   }
 }
 else
 {
   // The server encountered a failure while attempting to parse or process
   // the multi-update operation itself and did not attempt to process any
   // of the changes contained in the request.
 }


NOTE: This class, and other classes within the com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.unboundidds package structure, are only supported for use against Ping Identity, UnboundID, and Nokia/Alcatel-Lucent 8661 server products. These classes provide support for proprietary functionality or for external specifications that are not considered stable or mature enough to be guaranteed to work in an interoperable way with other types of LDAP servers.

It is from your link.
I use AD. looks like it is not applicable for me

@gstackoverflow Then I guess you're out of luck. There's a discussion of this here, where the only other option suggested is to use async operations, which I assume means using LdapConnection.asyncDelete
